# Is one nit enough to produce a new generation of head lice?

Tags: hair, removal, parasites, scalp, head-lice

The website below claims that one nit is sufficient to produce a new generation of head lice.

[Liceguard Link](http://www.liceguard-europe.com/lice-and-nits.html)

> Regardless of which treatment you apply, it is recommendable to remove all (or as many as possible) nits from the scalp, since even one nit is enough to produce a new generation of parasites, and the process itself is faster and more secure if you are get rid of lice and nits at the same time.

I wanted to ask if this is really true? Surely either a pregnant female louse or BOTH a male and female must be present in order for a new generation of head lice to occur?